# QGIS 3.10 and data dependencies

Tags: qgis, calculate-values

I have one table call "LR - Données", with 2 attributes: '`LR nom français`' and '`LR nom latin`'.
I have a point layer in a geopackage call "`Observations`" with 2 attributes: '`Nom français`' and '`Nom latin`'.

The attribute '`Nom français`' is a value relation:
[image: Nom français value relation structure]

The attribute '`Nom latin`' is also a value relation:
[image: Nom latin value relation structure]

Until here, everything works fine. But sometimes, the '`LR - Données`' table has update. So I set a dependence in my layer '`Observations`' with the '`LR- Données`' table.

Here is my problem. When I change for example a latin name in my table '`LR - Données`', the attribute in layer '`Observations`' change, and the old value comes into `()`. Which is fine in a way, cause it shows me changes. But how can I update all the value in my attribute table to get all the new values?

Comment: No one has the same problem?